# Use CSS to animate a box to fill a whole screen without any abrupt jumping

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following code which just draws a yellow box 80vh from the top of a container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<style>
:root {
  --t: 1s;
}
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.contain {
  position:relative;
  height:400vh;
  background:blue;
}
.box {
  position:absolute;
  top:80vh;
  height:400px;
  width:50vw;
  left:0;
  background:yellow;
  transition: position 0s linear var(--t),
    background var(--t) ease 0s,
    top var(--t) ease 0s,
    height var(--t) ease 0s,
    width var(--t) ease 0s;
}
input {
  display:none;
}
input:checked ~ .contain .box {
  position:fixed;
  background: pink;
  top:0;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="contain">
    <label class="box" for="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want a CSS only solution where by if I click on the yellow box, it will **smoothly** grow to fill the whole screen without any **abrupt** jumping effect.  My solution above works if your browser scroll position is at 0px (ie. at the top of the page).  But the moment you scroll say 100vh down, clicking on the yellow box causes it to jump downwards a bit before it grows, which I clarify in this 30 second video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hVNg-OPZ6Q .

Can anyone suggest how I can use CSS and HTML only to achieve a smooth transition for my yellow box to grow and fill the entire screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid what you're trying to achieve is not 100% possible with a css-only solution.

As the other answer stated, the main issue comes from the fact you're going to a fixed `position` from an `absolute` one. The thing is that the `position` property is not animatable, meaning that no matter how many seconds you apply to it in the `transition` property, it will have no effect.

The closest css-only solution would be to do that :

```
/* Some code  */

input:checked~.contain .box {
    background: pink;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Some code  */
```

The box will animate to fill the whole viewport but with a slightly different animation time to fill the whole height. Also the animation will start from the initial yellow box position and not from the bottom of the screen.

If you want to animate exactly how you described it in your post, you will necessarily have to use some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind the abrupt jumping effect is that in input:checked you have fixed position change it to absolute.

```
position:absolute;
```

Fixed position makes the element's position and dimension relative to its containing block that is the contain class whereas in absolute it is relative to initial containing block which is normally viewport: the browser window or the paper’s page box.

Comment: I tried using `transition: position 0s linear var(--t)` to delay the `position:fixed`.  But that didn't work. ANy other ideas?

Comment: I changed position in input:checked ~ .contain .box  from fixed to absolute and it worked absolutely fine.